# App is performing very slow ios

Tags: ios, iphone, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, fmdb

my app stucks for a long time if I press any button or want to  move from a view to another. I am performing transition in main thread, and other operations in background thread. But main problem is in FMDatabaseQueue.

Here is the timer profile:

[image]

I am trying to find out the actual problem. Still couldn't find it. Any help will be appreciated. Let me know if you want to know about any specific implementation.

Comment: By "performing transition in background thread" you mean the view transition code is performed in background thread?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr > No, sorry my mistake. Performing other operation in background thread. UI operations in main thread.

Comment: What does `SyncPoolController mediaSync` do?  Can you show code?

Comment: @Paulw11 > it check the db if there is any images not uploaded to the server. If there is something like this then it starts uploading it to the server.

Comment: How are you dealing with the background Threads? GCD, Operation oder just a perform?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff > The project I am working on is an old one. It has GCD and NSOperation mixture. I was thinking about this.

Comment: I can see al call from the operation to a method called updateStatus. Perhaps this method is doing something with the UI to show a progress indicator ? What are all this sync funtions for?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff > This app works in both offline and online. If someone make some changes offline it tries to sync whenever it is online. updateStatus post a local notification to all the listeners.

Comment: Local notification? I hope you mean only an NSNotification :)

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff > Yes. Sorry for misguiding.

Comment: What about debugging by removing actions from the background Threads step by step until it gets faster?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff > Thanks, yeah I tried it already and partially solved it. A few issues remaining though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean **(CMD + Shift + K)** the project.
2. Run again **(CMD + R)**

Worked for me.

Remember to perform all UI changes on main thread, don't perform any UI changes on background thread **(NOT RECOMMENDED)**.